# linking a library to an android ndk application in visual studio 2015

Tags: c++, android-ndk, visual-studio-2015, dynamic-linking

I've created a Native-Activity Application for Android in Visual Studio 2015. If I just run the example code, the app works. I want to use and external library in my app though. For this, I do the following:

1. Add the include dir to C/C++->General->Additional Include Directories
2. Add the lib/x86 path to Linker->General->Additional Library Directories
3. Add the library name to Linker->Input->Library Dependencies

With these settings I can use some library code in my project and get it compiled. If, for example, I should omit the library directory, the compiler complains about the unimplemented functions.

But if I run the generated apk on the emulator or android phone, it crashes instantly, even before any breakpoint is hit.

Even when I don't actually use the library (comment out all my own code), but just link it, the app crashes.

One clue I have is that, even while the library is used to compile the app, it is not copied into the apk file. I've unpacked the apk and it includes 2 files in lib\x86: gdbserver and libAndroid1.so (which is the compiled version of my native activity). But the library I linked is just not there.

I guess I am supposed to indicate somewhere in the project that I want my library included in the apk, but where do I do that?

Comment: _"it includes 2 files in lib\x86"_. So, just to make sure: your Android phone and the AVD you've created for use in the emulator are both x86-based?

Comment: no, the phone is ARM-based. VS generates two apk files: one for each platform. It depends on what configuration I choose when I compile and run. The ARM apk contains the same files, but in lib\armeabi-v7a.

Comment: Can you share the Android Logcat log for the issue you are experiencing?

Answer (score 0):

Step 2 should actually be: Add the lib\$(Platform) path to Linker->General->Additional Library Directories

I doubt that your Android device is running x86 (unless it is in the emulator). $(Configuration)will automatically resolve to Debug or Release, and $(Platform) will automatically resolve to ARM, ARM64, x86, etc.

Have a separate folder for each library Platform.